# Change the task name displayed by mix

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Hello there I have a module like this one:

```
Mix.Tasks.MyModule.Release.Deploy
```

and when I run mix help it is displayed like this:

```
my_module.release.deploy
```

How can I change that to

```
mymodule.release.deploy
```

I tried to use [Mix.Task.task_name/1](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html#task_name/1):

```
def task_name(_) do
  "mymodule.release.deploy"
end
```

but with no success. Am I missing something there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed. CamelCase is translated to lowercase with underscores between two capital letters. If you want `mymodule`, you better write it `Mymodule` in the first place.